# Text inside FlexBox with CSS not Appearing

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Goal: I have a main flex box with row display. Within each of these flexbox I will have card with text inside. When I create the card inside the flexbox I place p tags inside the card with the text, but it does not reflect. I want the text to dsiplay within each card.

Code

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container>div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10px;
  /*text-align: center;*/
  line-height: 70vh;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.funds-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
}

.transaction-card {
  width: 700px
}

.amount-card {
  width: 70%;
  height: 70px;
  max-width: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px auto 0 auto;
  padding: 1.5em;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <h1>The flex-direction Property</h1>

  <p>The "flex-direction: row;" stacks the flex items horizontally (from left to right):</p>

  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="funds-card">
      <div class="amount-card">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="transaction-card">
      2
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

[image: Text is outside the card.]

Answer (score 2):

Remove `line-height: 70vh;` property from the `.flex-container>div`

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container>div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10px;
  /*text-align: center;*/
  /*line-height: 70vh;*/
  font-size: 30px;
}

.funds-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
}

.transaction-card {
  width: 700px
}

.amount-card {
  width: 70%;
  height: 70px;
  max-width: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px auto 0 auto;
  padding: 1.5em;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <h1>The flex-direction Property</h1>

  <p>The "flex-direction: row;" stacks the flex items horizontally (from left to right):</p>

  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="funds-card">
      <div class="amount-card">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="transaction-card">
      2
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```